# iOS: showing/hiding UI elements dynamically

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have an app with a UITableView of results in a center column, and a little search bar at the top. I want to dynamically add/remove a button that says "reset search" and pin it to the top of the view.

There are a couple ways to go about it, and I'm worried that they both look ugly or hacky to me. To wit:

- Add the button in the storyboard editor, and show/hide it in code. The trouble is I've already got a bunch of views specified this way in the storyboard, and so positioning/selecting them is a huge pain since they overlap each other.
- Add the button in code. Except now my UI is specified in two places: the stuff that's in the storyboard, and the additional modifications that take place in the code.

What's the standard way of doing something like this? And how can I prevent my storyboards from becoming a big mess when I've got buttons/dialogs/etc. that need to be dynamically shown/hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well my first answer is to not use storyboards in the first place. However, I understand that's not helpful in this case.

If I were you, I would do option 2. It's a one off for this single button and it has a specific use case. It doesn't hurt to specify it in code. The following is for the

```
.h
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *resetButton;
```

And

```
.m
//I'm guessing you're using a VC, so I'd put this in viewDidLoad

self.resetButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:YOUR FRAME];
self.resetButton.alpha = 0.0;
//any other styling
[self.view addSubview:self.resetButton];
self.resetButton addTarget:self action:@selector(onReset) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

//and then add these three methods

- (void)onReset {
    //called when reset button is tapped
}

- (void)showResetButton {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.3 animations:^{
        self.resetButton.alpha = 1.0;
    }];
}

- (void)hideResetButton {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.3 animations:^{
        self.resetButton.alpha = 0.0;
    }];
}
```

Comment: transparent does not mean its hidden bro

Comment: If alpha = 0, no touch events are registered. It acts as hidden.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I have understood, but if you want to hide an object with an action, you can do so :

```
- (IBAction)myaction:(id)sender 
{
    self.object1.hidden = false ;
    self.object2.hidden = true ;
    self.object3.hidden = false ;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both ways are perfect, I personally prefer the Storyboard one because it lets you arrange the button more easily and it's easier to add constraints for auto-layout(if needed) in Interface Builder than in code.

For your second question: If your storyboard is cluttered and views are all over the place, I would suggest that you select your views from the side bar, rather thank trying to click on them. Also, if you want to move the selected view, adjust the coordinates in the Utilities panel instead of dragging it with the mouse.